# How to read an ADOQueryConnection with C# in Infopath 2013

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado, infopath

I am currently creating my first InfoPath Form with C# code on the back end.  It is connecting to a SQL Server DB as well.  When the form opens I want it to connect to our SQL Server DB and pull in the user's name and title automatically.  However, I'm rather stuck on what seems like a very simple task.

How do I read the data from an ADO Connection after I've executed the query?  Below is my code.  This seems so simple but I can't seem to figure it out.

AD_Mirror contains the ADO Connection to the DB and the appropriate table.  The CustomQuery is my attempt to filter this down by the user that is opening the form.

I then execute it in theory grabbing the user information I need.  Then I am unsure as to how to proceed.  I've searched all over for an answer, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
       //ADO Attempt
        AdoQueryConnection connection =
       (AdoQueryConnection)DataConnections["AD_Mirror"];

        string customQuery = " where SamAccountName = '" + userName + "'";
        string origCommand = connection.Command.ToString();
        //set the query to use the custom command
        connection.Command = origCommand + customQuery;
        //annnnnnddddd, now we run the query using our shiny new command           
         connection.Execute();
```

Comment: did you check out the [MSDN Example online AdoQueryConnection.Command property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.infopath.adoqueryconnection.command.aspx)

Comment: I saw that... but what do I do after the myAdoQueryConnection.Execute();?  I want to take the data I receive and populate fields on my form.

Comment: So I basically need to figure out how to use what I have above and mix it with something like a DataReader.  I haven't been able to get anything to work and a reader may not be the right idea anyways.

Comment: http://www.bizsupportonline.net/infopath2007/how-to-retrieve-infopath-form-sql-server-display-formcontrol.htm

Comment: Thanks for your replies.  So if I want to use DataReader with the above code how would I set it up?  I've tried "SqlDataReader reader = connection.ExecuteReader();" among other tries with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

So I had to separate out the connection from the SQL Query.  Then pull in a datatable to pull the data in.

```
    string queryString = origCommand + customQuery;  //Pull in Query
    string conn = connection.Connection;  //Grab Connection

                     using (OleDbConnection connection1 = new OleDbConnection(conn))
             {
                 OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection1);
                 command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                 try
                 {
                     connection1.Open();
                     OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
                     adapter.Fill(oSet);

                             string firstName = (oSet.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[9]).ToString();
                     firstName = firstName.Trim();
```

My query has First Name in Column 9 (hence the above ItemArray of 9).  You can set it tup to loop through this if you need to but I didn't.

Thanks